# How to restore lost custom.css in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, customization

While editing the custom.css file something unexpectedly happened.

Please help me in restoring the `.css` file.  I can see a `.css` file called custom.css in `subdirectory/wp-content/themes/attitude/css/custom.css`, but it doesn’t contain any code.  It's a blank file.

Comment: You need to tell more details about this. A better way to do some changes to a file is, after keeping a back up of the current file. :)

Comment: i am doing a wordpress site.i had created a custom.css file and made all styles in that file. it contains 100 s of lines.unexpectedly all the style i given to the site had gone. when i checked the custom.css file its seen blank.there was an inbuilt style.css file along with the theme.And after downloding the theme i created custom.css file

Comment: if the css file editor you used is still open you can undo. otherwise seems like no luck.

Comment: no. i have cosed that file from npp :( any other way??

Comment: you might find this link helpfull. http://superuser.com/questions/390204/how-to-restore-a-previous-version-of-file-in-notepad. what is the operating system you are using ?

Comment: ok.thanq.......windows7

Comment: OK, you might find the back up file in the given location in the discussion, try to open that files from npp. :)

Comment: Fixed spelling and grammar.

Comment: There might be a way to recover it from your browser's cache.

Answer (score 0):

If you're making these edits on your server (and this can even work if you're editing locally), you can restore your files from yesterday (or whenever they were last there) as that should fix the issue. All hosts have daily, weekly, and monthly backups that are available upon request.

P.S. Look into version control